# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')'

Tags: php

Ошибка: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' in Z:\home\localhost\www\jeka.ua\config\questions.php on line 10
PHP код:

```
    <?php
/**
* @question - вопрос
* @path - путь к картинке
* @isCorrect - правильный ли ответ на вопрос или нет
*/

$imgFolder = '/../images/'; 
return array(
    [   //question 1
        'question' => 'Выберите кота', 
        'images' => [
            [
                'path' => $imgFolder.'enoty1.jpg', 
                'isCorrect' => 'false'
            ],
            [
                'path' => $imgFolder.'cat1.jpg', 
                'isCorrect' => 'true'
            ], 
            [
                'path' => $imgFolder.'sea1.jpg', 
                'isCorrect' => 'false'
            ], 
            [
                'path' => $imgFolder.'tree1.jpg', 
                'isCorrect' => 'false'
            ],
        ]
    ],
    [   //question 2
        'question' => 'Выберите медведя', 
        'images' => [
            [
                'path' => $imgFolder.'earth1.jpg', 
                'isCorrect' => 'false'
            ], 
            [
                'path' => $imgFolder.'rose1.jpg', 
                'isCorrect' => 'false'
            ],
            [
                'path' => $imgFolder.'car1.jpg', 
                'isCorrect' => 'false'
            ], 
            [
                'path' => $imgFolder.'bear1.jpg', 
                'isCorrect' => 'true'
            ],
        ]
    ],
    [   //question 3
        'question' => 'Выберите собаку', 
        'images' => [
            [
                'path' => $imgFolder.'dog1.jpg', 
                'isCorrect' => 'true'
            ], 
            [
                'path' => $imgFolder.'horse1.jpg', 
                'isCorrect' => 'false'
            ],
            [
                'path' => $imgFolder.'pand1.jpg', 
                'isCorrect' => 'false'
            ], 
            [
                'path' => $imgFolder.'forest1.jpg', 
                'isCorrect' => 'false'
            ],
        ]
    ],
);
?>
```

Comment: Не стыдно задавать вопросы по поводу синтаксических ошибок? Вам указали строку в которой ошибка, притом это синтаксическая, не какая-то магическая из-за какой-то непонятной библиотеки без документации, а простая синтаксическая ошибка которая фиксится быстрее чем создание вопроса на SO

Comment: И как её пофиксить?

Answer (score 1):

```
return array(
       //question 1
        'question' => 'Выберите кота', 
        'images' => array(
            array(
                'path' => $imgFolder.'enoty1.jpg', 
                'isCorrect' => 'false'
            ),
            array(
                'path' => $imgFolder.'cat1.jpg', 
                'isCorrect' => 'true'
            ),
     ...
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.array.php